# Creating dynamic component Angular5 + using 3rd party module in it

Tags: angular

I am trying to create dynamic component as the template is coming as a string from a service. I am also using prime-ng in it.

```
  // Here we create the component.
  private createComponentFromRaw(template: string = `asdfg`) {

    // Now we create a new component. It has that template, and we can even give it data.
    const tmpCmp = Component({ template : `<p>hello</p>`, })(class {
      // the class is anonymous. But it's a quite regular angular class. You could add @Inputs,
      // @Outputs, inject stuff etc.
      val:number = 10;
      alert1() {
        alert('hhhh')
      }
      ngOnInit() { /* do stuff here in the dynamic component */}
    });

    // Now, also create a dynamic module.
    const tmpModule = NgModule({
      declarations: [tmpCmp, HelloComponent],
      imports: [FormsModule, SliderModule],
      entryComponents: [tmpCmp]
      // providers: [] - e.g. if your dynamic component needs any service, provide it here.
    })(class {});

    // Now compile this module and component, and inject it into that #vc in your current component template.
    this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
      .then((factories) => {
        const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
        this.cmpRef = f.create(this.injector, [], null, this.moduleRef);
        this.cmpRef.instance.name = 'my-dynamic-component';
        this.vc.insert(this.cmpRef.hostView);
      });
  }
```

The issue I am facing is, I use **SliderModule** from prime-ng in the imports array, the only thing rendered by this component is that slider only and any other html etc is not getting rendered, this happens whether I call prime-ng component in the template or not, you can see in template string.

Can anyone please explain me what I am doing wrong and how to call any 3rd party modules in dynamic components.

Comment: Can you reproduce your case on stackblitz?

Comment: I dint know how to use npm install in stackblitz.